# Finding records based on converted timezone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, timezone

I have records with a `created` column whose datetime is stored in UTC.

For instance, this is the datetime stored in one record: `2014-02-01 00:33:25`

But if I retrieve that record and confer it to CST, it'd look like this:

```
Article.find(1).created.in_time_zone('Central Time (US & Canada)') => Fri, 31 Jan 2014 18:33:25 CST -06:00
```

Which is a different day/month as far as that timezone goes.

The problem I'm having is finding records based on a date. So say I wanted to pull all records for January 31, 2014 (CST). I want to include my example record.

How do I do that in a Rails app? I'm running Rails 4.0.1 and Ruby 2.0.0 with Postgres 9.3.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AT TIME ZONE` to change timezone

```
Article.where("date(created AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'CST') = '01/31/2014'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Got some help outside of SO and got what I was looking for.

Say I wanted to find all records in a date range, this is what it'd be:

```
Article.where(created: Date.parse("January 1, 2014").in_time_zone('Central Time (US & Canada)').beginning_of_day.utc..Date.parse("January 31, 2014").in_time_zone('Central Time (US & Canada)').end_of_day.utc)
```